# how to get data from multiple jTextFilds and send it to printer using java gui

Tags: java, swing, printing

I made a marksheet program using java.swing in netbeans. I want to get data from jTextFields (multiple fields) and then print it (hard copy I mean). I have done it using only one field but I want to do it with all fields I have, which I am unable to do so.

Here is the printing method code:

```
private void printing(){
    try {

        Boolean complete=jTextField1.print();
        MessageFormat header=new MessageFormat("Result Card");
        MessageFormat footer=new MessageFormat("Page(0,number,integer)");

        if(complete){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done Printing");

        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing....");
        }
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here are Fields

```
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
```

Comment: Use a report generating tool to print your data.

Comment: any tutorial or link about how to do this

Comment: You can search for Java report generation. One such tool is Jasper Report

Comment: [Java Printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/), but I agree with Hovercraft, something like JasperReports will generally be easier

Comment: I just want to do something like this:  input in field 1: 45 ; input in field 2: 56 ; input in field 3: 67 and so on in pdf file